# How to use ttk combobox with keyboard entry using return key press as event

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to learn how to use ttk Combo box and got as far as setting it up, populating, getting it to respond to selection of a listed item using a button control and alternatively binding to the ComboboxSelected event. The latter works for listed items coded in but I am missing something to make it work for an entry typed into the Combo box. I can type in an item and it will respond if I click a button but typing in an item and pressing enter does not work. I am trying to get the combo box fully functional without a button.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

window = tk.Tk()
window.minsize(600, 400)
window.title("ttk Combo box")


def chooseNumbers():
    label.configure(text = "You Selected " + mynumber.get())

def callbackfn(event):
    label.configure(text = "You Have Selected " + mynumber.get())

label = ttk.Label(window, text = "Choose A Number")

label.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

mynumber = tk.StringVar()
combobox = ttk.Combobox(window, width = 15 , textvariable = mynumber,state='normal')
combobox['values'] = (5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,15)
combobox.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

button = ttk.Button(window, text = "Click Me", command = chooseNumbers)  # don't want this
button.grid(column = 1, row = 1)

combobox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",callbackfn)    # how to get this to work with keyboard entry?

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

window = tk.Tk()
window.minsize(600, 400)
window.title("ttk Combo box")


def chooseNumbers(event):
    label.configure(text = "You Selected " + mynumber.get())

def callbackfn(event):
    label.configure(text = "You Have Selected " + mynumber.get())

label = ttk.Label(window, text = "Choose A Number")

label.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

mynumber = tk.StringVar()
combobox = ttk.Combobox(window, width = 15 , textvariable = mynumber,state='normal')
combobox['values'] = (5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,15)
combobox.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

combobox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",callbackfn)    # how to get this to work with keyboard entry?
combobox.bind("<Return>",chooseNumbers)

window.mainloop()
```

When you press button `Enter`,It will show "You Selected x".Just bind a event `<Return>` and call a function.

Comment: Yes keyboard entry works without the need for a button now, many thanks.